# Animating position of UImageView

Tags: swift, interface-builder

I am trying to animate a UIImageView, to go up and down the y axis of another UIImageView, in order to create a db meter. 
Looks like this [image: dbmeter]

The pin is the little guy at the bottom. These are 2 UIImageViews. Basically I am going to get the db off a soundfile, and update the pin to show the db. I have started a timer, to count how long it takes, and for the sake of testing, I've tried moving the pin along with the seconds.

```
func startCounter(){
       counter += 1                
       clockLabel.text = "\(secs)"
       dbPin.center.y = CGFloat(counter)
    }
```

The pin is not moving at all, and I suspect it might have something to do with autolayout?

Comment: Your code should work, even without ```setNeedsLayout``` and even with autolayout. Are you doing something else? Are you on the main thread? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your

```
dbPin.center.y = CGFloat(counter)
```

to

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
     self.dbPin.center.y = CGFloat(counter)
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: ```layoutIfNeeded``` may be necessary, but the UIView animation is not exactly suited for this case, especially without options.

Comment: The title he wrote is "Animating..." :D